# Controlling all presented modals iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin iOS app where I am presenting several modals one after the other.

`Modal1 -> Modal2 -> Modal3 -> etc.`

I would like to control and move all of their Frames. Is there any way that I can access all the modals that I have presented?

I tried something like:

```
var rootView = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentedViewController;
        foreach (UIView v in rootView)
        {
            //some code
        }
```

Any tips would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following code :

```
public void GetAllMoadlViewController ()
    {

        UIViewController presentViewController = this.PresentingViewController;
        UIViewController lastVC = this;

        while(presentViewController!=null)
        {
            // One by one to get all ModalViewController that you present 
            var temp = presentViewController;

            presentViewController = presentViewController.PresentingViewController;

            lastVC = temp;

            //do some thing you want 

        }

    }
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for!